# How to Install MongoDB using shell script?

Tags: bash, mongodb

We can install MongoDB by placing the below code in shell script file

```
if [ ! -f /usr/bin/mongod ]; then<br>
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10<br>
  echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list<br>
  sudo apt-get -y update
  sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org<br>
else
  echo "mongo db already installed.  Skipping..."
fi
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: The `<br>` codes should obviously be excluded. The nomal way to post code is to simply indent it with four spaces.

Comment: Above shell script will be useful to install MongoDB directly from the shell script.

Comment: @VenkatM: If you want to document a solution on stackoverflow, rephrase your Question in that way that it is really a question and post your solution as an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Simulant: Thanks for the info. I have rephrase the question. Is that okay?
I will follow the above article for self answers from now on.

Comment: @VenkatM: not exactly. Post it as an aswer below your question. Like you answer a question of an other person.

Comment: @VenkatM: Did you get a solution for this Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I just change it a little bit and tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f /usr/bin/mongod ]
    then
        sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
        echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
        sudo apt-get update -y
        sudo apt-get install mongodb-org -y
        sudo mkdir -p /data/db
        sudo chown -R $USER /data/db 
        sudo chmod -R go+w /data/db
else
  echo "mongo db already installed.  Skipping..."
fi
mongod
```